# Designer of Xamarin Vs 2015 and vs 2017 not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, xamarin-studio

- after creating a project in  Visual studio when i try to open .xaml file  i see this error in the designer :

  ```
  Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform
  ```
- when i re-open the .xaml file it just keep throwing this error . "Could not initialize class mono.android.D3DImageFactory"
  i re-installed the jdk jre . i set the environment variables but it doesn't work 
  i also changes the cpu from configuration manager to x86 but it doesn't work
  i changed my sdk but also doesn't work 
  i downloaded visual studio 2017 with xamarin . still doesn't work 
  i contacted xamarin and microsoft about this . but no answer

system : windows 32-bit 
jdk : jdk.1.8.0_144 32 bit 
jre : jdk.1.8.0_144 32 bit

i spent 3 days trying to fix this error but no result . if you have a solution for this problem i will be thankful

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class mono.android.D3DImageFactory
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at mono.android.DesignerSession.initializePlatformSpecific(DesignerSession.java:86)
at mono.android.DesignerSession.(DesignerSession.java:75)
at mono.android.Project.createSession(Project.java:382)
at mono.android.Project.processMessage(Project.java:414)
at mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`

update : I contacted Microsoft About this Issue , they said next versions of Xamaring Will not Support 32 bit systems . I just Downloaded The previous Version , now It Works

Comment: Looks like you installed the wrong version of something. It's trying to load a 64-bit DLL into your 32-bit OS. Read the error message: *Can't load AMD **64 bit .dll** on a **IA 32-bit platform***. You said *system: window 32-bit*, so clearly you can't load a 64-bit .dll - you don't have a 64-bit system. Read the words in the message, instead of just randomly trying different things hoping it will fix itself along the way.

Comment: I think Xamarin isn't compatible with 32 bit OS'es. Install a 64 bit OS, unless you have an ancient machine (which will not run at all VS) having a 64 bit OS is always better.

Comment: This is a Java error message and the cause is explained in the error.  This is an old bug that was fixed back in 4.2.x(?), what version of Xamarin are you installing? Search bugzilla as the bug and the Xamarin version that fixes it are listed there...

Comment: @KenWhite thanks for your answer , i can't figure out where is the 64 bit dll that i need to change  .cause i have 32 bit jdk and jre  , and  they work great with android studio ,

Comment: @Gusman  idon't know that xamarin don't support 32 bit os'es . do you have any resources about that ?

Comment: @KenWhite thanks for your answer , i am using tha last version.  Xamarin 4.6.0.299 and Xamarin.Android 7.4.0.21 . i think is a bug , cause i don't have any 64 bit dll in my os . the 32 bit jdk jre and SDK that i am using works fine with android studio . and eclipse .

Comment: I have no idea what you do or don't have installed. The error message is pretty clear. It appears to be related to mono, based on the exception you said it's throwing. I can't see your system from here, so I can't tell you what you might have wrong or whether it's a bug or not (although @SushiHangover seems to have pointed you to one). I know you don't have a 64-bit OS, which is exactly the problem - you're trying to load a 64-bit DLL in a 32-bit OS (which I said very clearly in my previous comment). You cannot mix 64-bit DLLs and a 32-bit OS, and something you've installed is trying.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks a lot . i re-installed all jdk , jre , Ndk versions i downloaded a new Sdk  . also installed Visual studio 2017 with the last version of xamarin but it doesn't work . i knew that i can't use a 64 bit dll in a 32 bit os . what i don't know is where is the 64 dll that is causing the problem . cause all version  that i use are 32 bit . thanks in advance Ken

Comment: @ SushiHangover thanks . i am using  i am using tha last version. Xamarin 4.6.0.299 and Xamarin.Android 7.4.0.21 . visual studio 2017

Comment: Your platform is 32bit, the dll was compiled for 64bit. That doesnt match, your windows and jdk wont fix that. Get a .dll for 32bit.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFTthanks for your answer . can you please tell me which .dll that i need to get ? and where i can get that dll . cause xamarin don't offer any dll's.

Comment: Sorry for  any inconvenience, SushiHangover is right, you could see this [Bugzilla report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59195) and this [explanation](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/102247/cant-load-amd-64-bit-dll-on-a-ia-32-bit-platform.html).